# Security question. Ubuntu installation on windows PC

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, security

I am installing Ubuntu alongside windows 7 because I believe Ubuntu is more secure (in terms of viruses, spyware etc).
So the computer will be contain both OSs. In such a situation, is Ubuntu still as secure as if it was the only OS on the computer?

Or is it more vulnerable because viruses can get onto the Ubuntu partition when using Windows OS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use WUBI, then it is a little bit less secure.

If you do a proper ubuntu install then it can be considered as safe as if it was alone. Technically it is possible for a virus running on your windows installation to make changes to your ubuntu installation. But it is a hard job because windows doesn't support the linux partitions used in ubuntu, so the virus have to contain a file system driver for those linux partitions. This is a very very unlikely situation and I think there is no such virus for windows which does such things.

So you can consider your ubuntu installation as safe as if it was alone.

Answer (score 0):

Just as secure as running it standalone. Windows cannot even access the windows partition without special software, and even if a virus did somehow find it's way onto there when you booted Ubuntu it wouldn't do anything, it would just sit there unable to do anything, Ubuntu being virus free doesn't just mean it won't get them, it means they just plain do not work.

Comment: Nothing is completely secure, and Ubuntu is not virus-free.

Comment: The completely secure term was misleading. I will edit that, however Ubuntu is for all intents and purposes virus free (just not malware free, these two are different) (there are an EXTREMELY small number of viruses that effect elf executables, and most of these are only theoretical research), and seeing as the question was mainly asking about how windows affects security it is still just as secure as without windows.

Comment: Here is an almost complete list of known viruses https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Linuxvirus#Viruses as you can see, nearly all of them are "proofs of concepts" and labeled as "you won't get this one" or "harmless"